# Do i need 32 AND 64 bits PDB symbols? Are they equal or not?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm generating both RELEASE|x86 and RELEASE|x64 .msi installer for my c# .NET app.

For debugging on a client machine, do i need to have also both (x86 AND x64) PDF files?

**Edited**: The .exe is included on the very same build configuration for each installer

Comment: Are you also building both x86 and x64 versions of your .exe file, or are you targeting only Any CPU and including the same .exe in both MSIs?

Comment: No answers after 4 years?